# Efficient memory allocation for large nested vectors

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

I'm creating a huge matrix that is stored inside nested vectors:

```
typedef vector<vector<pair<unsigned int, char>>> Matrix;
```

The outer vector will eventually contain ~400.000 vectors that which each contain ~220 pairs at max (most contain less). This takes about 1GB of RAM and is done like this:

```
Matrix matrix;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    vector<pair<unsigned int, char>> row;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        // ...calculations...
        row.push_back( pair<unsigned int, char>(x, y) );
    }
    matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

The first 20% go quite fast but the larger the outer vector grows, the slower gets the whole process. I'm pretty sure that there is some optimization possible, but I'm not an expert on this field. Are there any simple tricks to speed this up? Or are there any major faults in my attempt?

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough memory to allocate them all? Maybe your OS is working with a swap file...

Comment: I am guessing that if you need a matrix that big, the matrix will be a sparse matrix. In that case you are probably better off handling the matrix as such. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: @AlexanderChertov Yes, I'm sure that there is enough memory.

Comment: @doron Thanks, but this is already a sparse matrix. The 220 elements per row is just the maximum.

Comment: @Niko, then the problem is as guys suggested. The elements are copied over when the (outer) vector grows. Consider list<vector<pair<unsigned int, char>>> or something else that doesn't force you to copy a lot of data on push_back(). vector< shared_ptr<vector<pair<uint,char>>> > could be a viable alternative.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov If he's using c++11, then growing a vector of ~400.000 vectors or ~400.000 shared pointers is imho comparable. In c++03 you would be totally right though.

Comment: Because C++11 has move semantics.

Comment: @Niko to expand on that: when growing a vector, it first allocates a new chunk of memory to contain everything, then moves all the stuff it already has to the new place, then deallocates the old memory chunk. In c++03 moving the stuff requires to copy the contained object (so a copy of your inner vector), in c++11 the inner object is just moved - and moving a vector is very fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better to just use a single one dimensional vector and wrap up the row, column indexing in some functions/class. This way the memory for the entire matrix is guaranteed to be contiguous.

And instead of using `push_back` allocate the entire matrix up front:

```
std::vector<pair<unsigned int, char>> matrix(rows * cols);
```

Comment: @Andrew in this case it should be faster without it

Comment: Thank you. Squeezing this all into a single vector requires to much changes to the other code, but the reserve/preallocate stuff seems to work. One follow up question: If I do `vector.reserve(10);` and then copy this vector, does that lead to memory being reserved for 2 * 10 elements?

Comment: @Niko, in most implementations it won't, since the memory will be allocated independently for the copy.

Comment: I'm not sure that the single vector solution is appropriate here, since he definitely indicated that his vector was ragged, and that most of the lines contained significantly less entries than the maximum.

Comment: @James Kanze If the number of elements in each row doesn't change (or change very seldom) I would probably still use a single block of memory together with a vector of pointers to each row.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck That's a possible solution, but a bit more complex to put into effect.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the obvious optimization.
If you know the number of rows before you start filling the values (or usable upper bound), just reserve the space beforehand. The most time spend when pushing_back a lot of values is spend by reallocating memory and copying already contained values.

```
Matrix matrix(rows);
for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    vector<pair<unsigned int, char>> row(cols);
    for(unsigned j; j < cols; j++) {
        row[j] = // value
    }
    matrix[i] = row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the VS 2010 compiler, the following turned out to work best:

```
Matrix matrix;
matrix.reserve(rows);

vector<pair<unsigned int, char>> row;
row.reserve(cols);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        // ...calculations...
        row.push_back( pair<unsigned int, char>(x, y) );
    }
    matrix.push_back(row);
    row.clear();
}
```

Creating just a single vector that is used to build up all the rows consumes much less memory than creating a fresh one that allocates memory for "cols" entries every time. Not really sure why that is though.

However, I'm accepting Andreas' answer as this one is only a solution for my specific case while his answer provided the general information needed for such optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a lot of data copying when the outer vector grows. Consider changing your typedef to

```
typedef vector< shared_ptr< vector<pair<unsigned int, char>> > > Matrix;
```

and doing `matrix.reserve(rows)` before you start fililng it with values.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that he dynamically allocate all of the nested `vector`?

Comment: If the number of elements in the outer vector isn't known in advance, yes, I would try it.